# Creating spreadsheet with data using Google Sheets API from browser

Tags: javascript, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I have the following data table, I want to create a spreadsheet with using Google Sheets API.
I could use the subsequent fetch code snippet to create a spreadsheet with desired title and sheet name.

```
const tableInfo = [
  ["Name", "Age", "Score", "Date", "Tags"],
  ["Name1", "30", "2050", "13-12-2011", "First"],
  ["Name2", "40", "250", "11-12-2001", "First"],
  ["Name3", "35", "1345", "13-02-2011", "Second"]
]
const initialData = {
  properties: {
    title: `${fileName}`
  },
  sheets: [{
    properties: {
      title: `${sheetName}`
    },
  }, ],
};
fetch("https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets", {
    method: "POST",
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
      Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
    },
    body: JSON.stringify(initialData),
  })
  .then((doc) => {
    return doc.json();
  })
  .then((doc) => {
    console.log("Doc Created!")
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    console.log("error");
  });
```

After creating this doc I couldn't update the created sheet with my table data, I get Status 400 error code

```
var docId = doc.spreadsheetId;
var sheetId = doc.sheets[0].properties.sheetId;
var sheetData = [];
sheetData.push({
  range: {
    sheetId: sheetId
  },
  values: tableInfo,
});
var sheetBody = {
  data: sheetData,
  valueInputOption: "RAW",
};
fetch(`https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets/${docId}:batchUpdate`, {
    method: "POST",
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
      Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
      Accept: "application/json",
    },
    body: sheetBody,
  })
  .then((updateDoc) => {
    console.log("Doc Updated!! ", updateDoc);
  })
  .catch((err) => {
    console.log("Update Error: ", err);
  });
```

What am I doing wrong with the above code?

Also, Is it not possible to create a spreadsheet along with data using Google Sheets API? Should I create the file first and then update it with data?

Also please note the tableInfo data is dynamic, it could have 5 columns or 50 columns, 10 rows, or 100s of rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

About `After creating this doc I couldn't update the created sheet with my table data, I get Status 400 error code` and `What am I doping wrong with the above code?`, when I saw your script, I noticed the following modification points.

#### Modification points:

- Your endpoint of `https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets/${docId}:batchUpdate` is for "Method: spreadsheets.batchUpdate". But, your showing request body is not correct. In this case, how about using "Method: spreadsheets.values.update"?
- The fetch API is run with the asynchronous process. In your script, the 2nd request is run before the 1st request is completely finished.
- In the case of `.catch((error) => {console.log("error");})`, `error` is not correctly shown.

When these points are reflected in your script, how about the following modification?

#### Modified script:

```js
const token = "###"; // Please set your access token.
const fileName = "sample filename"; // Please set Spreadsheet title.
const sheetName = "sampleSheet1"; // Please set sheet name.

const tableInfo = [
  ["Name", "Age", "Score", "Date", "Tags"],
  ["Name1", "30", "2050", "13-12-2011", "First"],
  ["Name2", "40", "250", "11-12-2001", "First"],
  ["Name3", "35", "1345", "13-02-2011", "Second"]
]
const initialData = {
  properties: { title: `${fileName}` },
  sheets: [{ properties: { title: `${sheetName}` } }],
};
fetch("https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets", {
  method: "POST",
  headers: {
    "Content-Type": "application/json",
    Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
  },
  body: JSON.stringify(initialData),
})
  .then((doc) => {
    return doc.json();
  })
  .then((doc) => {
    console.log("Doc Created!")

    fetch(`https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets/${doc.spreadsheetId}/values/${sheetName}?valueInputOption=USER_ENTERED`,
      {
        method: "PUT",
        headers: {
          "Content-Type": "application/json",
          Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
          Accept: "application/json",
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({ values: tableInfo }),
      }
    )
      .then((updateDoc) => {
        console.log("Doc Updated!! ", updateDoc);
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log("Update Error: ", err);
      });

  })
  .catch((error) => {
    console.log(error);
  });
```

- When this script is run, a new Spreadsheet is created and the values of `tableInfo` are put into the 1st sheet of the created Spreadsheet.

#### Note:

- In this modification, it supposes that your access token can be used for creating a new Spreadsheet and putting the values to Spreadsheet with Sheets API. Please be careful about this.

#### References:

- [Method: spreadsheets.batchUpdate](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/batchUpdate)
- [Method: spreadsheets.values.update](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets.values/update)

### Added:

From your following reply,

> I applied your changes and I get this error. {   "error": {     "code": 400,     "message": "Invalid values[1][4]: list_value {\n  values {\n    string_value: "First"\n  }\n}\n",     "status": "INVALID_ARGUMENT"   } } My apologies I forgot to mention that the data columns (in this case "Tags") may contain array of values. how do I fix this.

> tableInfo: [["Name","StartDate","Flagged","Tags","Score"],["User1","2023-07-24",true,["First"],"3000"],["User2","2023-07-28",true,["Second"],"2450"],["User3","2023-08-01",true,["Third"],"0"]]}]

I couldn't notice that your value of `tableInfo` is different from your actual situation. And, I think that your actual value is an invalid array. If your actual value is as follows,

```js
const tableInfo = [
  ["Name","StartDate","Flagged","Tags","Score"],
  ["User1","2023-07-24",true,["First"],"3000"],
  ["User2","2023-07-28",true,["Second"],"2450"],
  ["User3","2023-08-01",true,["Third"],"0"]
];
```

Please modify this as follows and test it again.

```js
const tableInfo = [
  ["Name","StartDate","Flagged","Tags","Score"],
  ["User1","2023-07-24",true,["First"],"3000"],
  ["User2","2023-07-28",true,["Second"],"2450"],
  ["User3","2023-08-01",true,["Third"],"0"]
].map(e => e.flat());
```

By this modification, each element of `tableInfo` is flattened.

Comment: Thank you @Tanaike for your response. I applied your changes and I get this error. ```{
  "error": {
    "code": 400,
    "message": "Invalid values[1][4]: list_value {\n  values {\n    string_value: \"First\"\n  }\n}\n",
    "status": "INVALID_ARGUMENT"
  }
}``` My apologies I forgot to mention that the data columns (in this case "Tags") may contain array of values. how do I fix this. Thank you!

Comment: tableInfo: ```[["Name","StartDate","Flagged","Tags","Score"],["User1","2023-07-24",true,["First"],"3000"],["User2","2023-07-28",true,["Second"],"2450"],["User3","2023-08-01",true,["Third"],"0"]]}]```

Comment: @Safi Thank you for replying. I couldn't notice that your value of `tableInfo` is different from your actual situation. I think that this is due to my poor English skill. I deeply apologize for my poor English skill. About your actual value, I added the modification point. Please confirm it.

Comment: @Tanaike..no need to apologise. it was my mistake i didn't explain how my data is. Important thing is your solution worked and I could update my worksheet with my data. Thank you very much.

Comment: Although flattening the array will work, it will result in issues if my row is like this ["User1","2023-07-24",true,["First", "second"],"3000"] and we flatten this row it'll give ["User1","2023-07-24",true,"First", "second", "3000"], increasing the no. of columns. Am I correct? any idea how do we solve this? Thank you very much for your time

Comment: @Safi Thank you for replying. I'm glad your 2nd question was resolved. About your 3rd question, I would like to support you. But, I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand your 3rd question. Can I ask you about the detail of it? First, I would like to correctly understand your 3rd question.

Comment: Let me try to explain better here. I have 5 columns ["Name","StartDate","Flagged","Tags","Score"], if my first row is this "User3","2023-08-01",true,["Third"],"0"] we can flatten the this row to this ["User3","2023-08-01",true,"Third","0"] no problem. Let's say I have another row ["User1","2023-07-24",true,["First", "second"],"3000"] where column 4 ("Tags") is array with 2 items. I want the array ["First", "second"] as comma separated values like "First", "second" under column 4 ("Tags). Hope I have explained it better now. Thank you @Tanaike for your time and effort, really appreciate it.

Comment: @Safi Thank you for replying. Unfortunately, although I'm not sure whether I could correctly understand your 3rd question, how about `[["User1","2023-07-24",true,["First", "second"],"3000"]].map(e => e.map(f => Array.isArray(f) ? f.join(",") : f))`? If I misunderstood your 3rd question, I apologize.

Comment: I have another question regarding Sheets API, I want to check whether a file exists by filename and if it does I want to update it with new data. I know Drive API gives a file list, but is there way to get the spreadsheetId as well so that I can update the files with new data

Comment: @Safi Thank you for replying. From `Awesome!! Thanks for your help @Tanaike`, I understood that your 3rd question was resolved. About your 4th question of `I have another question regarding Sheets API, I want to check whether a file exists by filename and if it does I want to update it with new data. I know Drive API gives a file list, but is there way to get the spreadsheetId as well so that I can update the files with new data`, I would like to support you.

Comment: @Safi But the 4th question of replying is new question, and that is different from your question. So can you post it as new question? Because when your initial question is changed by comment, other users who see your question are confused. By posting it as new question, users including me can think of it. If you can cooperate to resolve your new issue, I'm glad. Can you cooperate to resolve your new question?